# метод unshift не работает нужным образом

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Может есть какие то идеи, почему unshift добавляем в конец массива, а не в начало? И сортировка что то не помогает.

code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    counters: [{
      id: 0
    }],
    greeting: "<div class='logo'>Final countdown</div>",
    timeNow: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
    currentId: 0
  },
  components: {
    DinoCount
  },
  
  methods: {

    addCount() {
      this.counters.unshift({
        id: this.currentId
      })
      this.currentNum = this.currentNum + 1
      return this.counters.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)
    },

    clearScene() {
      this.counters = []
    }

  },
  created: function() {
    // время
    setInterval(() => {
      this.timeNow = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

[ссылка на фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/_jack/Lmt63dx9/562/)

Comment: потому что Вы увеличиваете счетчик в переменной `currentNum`, а в массив добавляете `currentId`, которое всегда одинаковое

Comment: @Дмытрык Действительно, вот так лохонулся) 
Но дело не в этом всё равно, я там уже с десяток вариаций попробовал уже, и сортировал от текущего времени добавления и упорно добавляет в конец, хотя при такой сортировке и push в начало добавить должен, вот как тут, например при добавлении:
[ссылка](http://jack-dev.zzz.com.ua/)
Оттуда сортировка. Оно не критично, просто хотелось анимацию прикрутить и смысл теряется если вниз уходить будет поток добавленных объектов. Вот код поправил на фиддле, тот же результат пока, не могу понять с чем связанно.